# How to link libraries on eclipse in this situation?

Tags: c++, eclipse, cmake, fltk

I have a c++ project can be complied well by using cmake.

But when I go to eclipse, there are some problems.

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
undefined reference to `FcMatrixRotate' test_new        line 0, external location: fl_font.cxx  C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `FcPatternAddBool'   test_new        line 0, external location: fl_font.cxx  C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `FcPatternAddDouble' test_new        line 0, external location: fl_font.cxx  C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `FcPatternAddInteger'    test_new        line 0, external location: fl_font.cxx  C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `FcPatternAddMatrix' test_new        line 0, external location: fl_font.cxx  C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `FcPatternAddString' test_new        line 0, external location: fl_font.cxx  C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `FcPatternCreate'    test_new        line 0, external location: fl_font.cxx  C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `FcPatternDestroy'   test_new        line 0, external location: fl_font.cxx  C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `FcUtf8Len'  test_new        line 0, external location: fl_font.cxx  C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `FcUtf8ToUcs4'   test_new        line 0, external location: fl_font.cxx  C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `jpeg_calc_output_dimensions'    test_new        line 0, external location: Fl_JPEG_Image.cxx    C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `jpeg_CreateDecompress'  test_new        line 0, external location: Fl_JPEG_Image.cxx    C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `jpeg_destroy_decompress'    test_new        line 0, external location: Fl_JPEG_Image.cxx    C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `jpeg_finish_decompress' test_new        line 0, external location: Fl_JPEG_Image.cxx    C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `jpeg_read_header'   test_new        line 0, external location: Fl_JPEG_Image.cxx    C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `jpeg_read_scanlines'    test_new        line 0, external location: Fl_JPEG_Image.cxx    C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `jpeg_resync_to_restart' test_new        line 0, external location: Fl_JPEG_Image.cxx    C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `jpeg_start_decompress'  test_new        line 0, external location: Fl_JPEG_Image.cxx    C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `jpeg_std_error' test_new        line 0, external location: Fl_JPEG_Image.cxx    C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `jpeg_stdio_src' test_new        line 0, external location: Fl_JPEG_Image.cxx    C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `XftDrawChange'  test_new        line 0, external location: fl_font.cxx  C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `XftDrawCreate'  test_new        line 0, external location: fl_font.cxx  C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `XftDrawSetClip' test_new        line 0, external location: fl_font.cxx  C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `XftDrawString32'    test_new        line 0, external location: fl_font.cxx  C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `XftFontMatch'   test_new        line 0, external location: fl_font.cxx  C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `XftFontOpen'    test_new        line 0, external location: fl_font.cxx  C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `XftFontOpenPattern' test_new        line 0, external location: fl_font.cxx  C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `XftFontOpenXlfd'    test_new        line 0, external location: fl_font.cxx  C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `XftTextExtents32'   test_new        line 0, external location: fl_font.cxx  C/C++ Problem
```

In eclipse, I go to project-> properties-> c/c++ build-> settings-> tool settings-> GCC C++ linker-> libraries, then add jpeg, Xft and fontconfig in "Libraries (-l)", and add /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu in "Library search path (-L)". But it's not work.

Here's my CMakeLists.txt which works well in cmake.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

PROJECT(PROSTVIEW)

SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE DEBUG)
SET(CMAKE_CXX__FLAGS -O3 -pipe -ffast-math -Wno-deprecated)

# Chargement Package
# FLTK
 FIND_PACKAGE ( FLTK )
 IF ( FLTK_FOUND )
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${FLTK_INCLUDE_DIR} )
 ENDIF ( FLTK_FOUND )

# ITK
FIND_PACKAGE ( ITK )
IF ( ITK_FOUND )
    INCLUDE( ${USE_ITK_FILE} )
ENDIF( ITK_FOUND )

# VTK
FIND_PACKAGE ( VTK )
IF ( VTK_FOUND )
    INCLUDE( ${USE_VTK_FILE} )
ENDIF( VTK_FOUND )
SET(VTK_LIBRARIES vtkCommon vtkRendering vtkWidgets vtkGraphics vtkGenericFiltering vtkzlib)

# vtkFlRenderWindowInteractor
SET(VTKFL_INCLUDE_DIR "include/vtkfl")
SET(VTKFL_CPP 
${VTKFL_INCLUDE_DIR}/vtkFlRenderWindowInteractor.cxx)

# Auxiliary_Tools
SET(AT_DIR "include/Auxiliary_Tools")
SET(AT_INCLUDE_DIR ${AT_DIR}/include)
SET(AT_LIBRARY_DIR ${AT_DIR}/lib)

#Nifty
SET(NII_DIR "include/nifti")
SET(NII_SRC 
${NII_DIR}/vtkNIfTIReader.cxx
${NII_DIR}/vtkNIfTIWriter.cxx
${NII_DIR}/vtkAnalyzeReader.cxx
${NII_DIR}/vtkAnalyzeWriter.cxx
${NII_DIR}/vtknifti1_io.cxx
${NII_DIR}/vtkznzlib.cxx)

#Other include
SET(PROSTVIEW_INCLUDE_DIR "include")
SET(PROSTVIEW_SRC
${PROSTVIEW_INCLUDE_DIR}/ContourTmt.cpp
${PROSTVIEW_INCLUDE_DIR}/conversion.cpp 
${PROSTVIEW_INCLUDE_DIR}/TmtMatrix.cpp) 

# VOLUME Widget
SET(VOLUME_WIDGET_DIR "include/GUI")
SET(VOLUME_WIDGET 
${VOLUME_WIDGET_DIR}/VOLUME_Loader.cpp 
${VOLUME_WIDGET_DIR}/VOLUME_Widget.cpp 
${VOLUME_WIDGET_DIR}/VOLUME_Mouse_Widget.cpp 
${VOLUME_WIDGET_DIR}/VOLUME_3DView.cpp 
${VOLUME_WIDGET_DIR}/CONTOUR_Loader.cpp 
${VOLUME_WIDGET_DIR}/ProstView.cpp)

# MODULES
SET(MODULE_DIR "Module")

# SEGMENTATION
SET(SEGMENTATION_DIR "Module/Segmentation")
SET(SEGMENTATION 
${SEGMENTATION_DIR}/DDC2D.cpp 
${SEGMENTATION_DIR}/DDC3D.cpp 
${SEGMENTATION_DIR}/DDC3DHu.cpp 
${SEGMENTATION_DIR}/DDC3DPlus.cpp 
${SEGMENTATION_DIR}/DDC3DBal.cpp 
${SEGMENTATION_DIR}/IMAGE_ENERGY.cpp 
${SEGMENTATION_DIR}/REGULARIZATION.cpp 
${SEGMENTATION_DIR}/OPTIMAL_SURFACE_DETECTION.cpp 
${SEGMENTATION_DIR}/OPTIMAL_MULTIPLE_SURFACES_DETECTION.cpp 
${SEGMENTATION_DIR}/RESAMPLE_From_Prostate.cpp
${SEGMENTATION_DIR}/RECTAL_WALL_US.cpp 
${SEGMENTATION_DIR}/BLADDER_MRI.cpp 
${SEGMENTATION_DIR}/RECTUM_MRI.cpp 
${SEGMENTATION_DIR}/REGION_GROWING.tpp )

#MESH
SET(MESH_DIR "Module/Mesh")
SET(MESH
${MESH_DIR}/GENERIC_MESH.cpp
${MESH_DIR}/ELLIPSOID_MESH.cpp
${MESH_DIR}/PROSTATE_MESH.cpp
${MESH_DIR}/TUBULAR_MESH.cpp
${MESH_DIR}/OPEN_MESH.cpp
${MESH_DIR}/QUADRIC_MESH.cpp
${MESH_DIR}/ELLIPTICAL_CYLINDER_MESH.cpp 
${MESH_DIR}/CONTOURS_MAN_MESH.cpp)

#STUDY
SET(STUDY_DIR "Module/Statistics")
SET(STUDY
${STUDY_DIR}/PROFILE.cpp
${STUDY_DIR}/Histogram.cpp
${STUDY_DIR}/HISTOGRAM_FROM_MESH.cpp
${STUDY_DIR}/TRAINING_SET_ALIGNMENT.cpp
${STUDY_DIR}/APPEARANCE_MODEL.cpp)

# MOMENTS
SET(MOMENTS_DIR "Module/Moments")
SET(MOMENTS 
${MOMENTS_DIR}/KRAWTCHOUK_Moments.tpp 
${MOMENTS_DIR}/TCHEBICHEF_Moments.tpp 
${MOMENTS_DIR}/GEOMETRIC_Moments.tpp)

#VALIDATION
SET(VALIDATION_DIR "Module/Evaluation")
SET(VALIDATION 
${VALIDATION_DIR}/Metrics.cpp)

# Include et Link Directories
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${FLTK_INCLUDE_DIR} ${VTK_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${VTKFL_INCLUDE_DIR} ${AT_INCLUDE_DIR} ${NII_DIR} ${PROSTVIEW_INCLUDE_DIR} ${VOLUME_WIDGET_DIR} ${MODULE_DIR})
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${FLTK_LIBRARY_DIR} ${VTK_LIBRARY_DIRS} ${AT_LIBRARY_DIR} ${PROSTVIEW_INCLUDE_DIR} ${VOLUME_WIDGET_DIR} ${MODULE_DIR})

# Sources
SET(SRC main.cpp) 

# Executables and "stand-alone " librairies
ADD_EXECUTABLE(PROSTVIEW ${SRC} ${PROSTVIEW_SRC} ${VTKFL_CPP} ${VOLUME_WIDGET} ${SEGMENTATION} ${MESH} ${STUDY} ${MOMENTS} ${VALIDATION} ${NII_SRC})

# Linkage
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(PROSTVIEW  ${FLTK_LIBRARIES} ${VTK_LIBRARIES} ${ITK_LIBRARIES} libfontconfig.so libXft.so)
```

I'm working with my professor who prefer eclipse, so I need to make it work in eclipse. What do I miss in my configure?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with Eclipse but (from a cursory glance) because you forget to link to three libraries in your CMakeLists.txt file, from the looks of it you need to link to FontConfig, libjpeg and the X libraries. When you are using CMake with Eclipse, Eclipse uses CMake for building and does not manage the build itself.

Comment: But it works well when I am using cmake without eclipse. I've add TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(PROSTVIEW libfontconfig.so libXft.so) in my cmakelists.txt.